# Algebra Polynomial proble

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a problem about polynomial. Let $p$ be a complex polynomial with degree $m$. Suppose there exist $x_0,x_1,...,x_m$ distinct real numbers such that $p(x_i)$ are real numbers for $i=0,1,..,m$. Prove that all coefficients of $p$ are reals.

Is there any theoretical knowledge for this problem? I did not see such type of problem

Comment: you can try
Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $y_i=p(x_i) \in \mathbb{R}$. The $m+1$ equations:

$$a_0 + a_1 x+i + a_2 x_i^2 + \cdots + a_m x_i^m = y_i \quad \quad i = 0,1,\cdots,m$$

form a linear system with $m+1$ unknowns $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_m$. The system is uniquely determined since its determinant is that of a [Vandermond matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Properties) with distinct entries $x_i \ne x_j$. Since all coefficients $x_i,y_i$ are real, the solution of the system is real as well, so all $a_j$ are real, thus so is $p(x)$.

As a side comment, the solution obtained in this way is precisely the interpolating polynomial through the points $(x_i,y_i)$ as hinted by @Ben in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

By CRT = Chinese Remainder the system $\, p \equiv r_i\pmod{x\!-x_i}$ has a *unique* solution $\, p\in \Bbb R[x]\,$ of degree $\,\le m.\,$ This persists as the unique such solution in $\,\Bbb C[x].$

Comment: Note: Lagrange / Newton interpolation is a special case of CRT.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the case where $m=2$.  This this case, $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.  Suppose that $x_0$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ are distinct real numbers such that $p(x_i)$ is also real.

Then, 
$$
p(x_2)-p(x_1)=a(x_2^2-x_1^2)-b(x_2-x_1)=(x_2-x_1)(a(x_2+x_1)+b).
$$
Since $p(x_2)$, $p(x_1)$, and $x_2-x_1$ are real, $a(x_2+x_1)+b$ is also real.  Similarly, $a(x_1+x_0)+b$ is also real.

Since $a(x_2+x_1)+b$ and $a(x_1+x_0)+b$ are real,
$$
a(x_2+x_1)+b-(a(x_1+x_0)+b)=a(x_2-x_0)
$$
is also real.  Since $x_2-x_0$ is real, $a$ is also real.  Since $a$ is real and $a(x_2+x_1)+b$ is real, $b$ is real, since $ax_2^2+bx_2+c$ is real and $a$, $b$, and $x_2$ are real, then $c$ is also real.

Comment: ok thanks i also so this fact. But about generalization? You see $deg(p)=m$ but there are $x_0,...,x_m$ $m+1$ indices. What i miss?

Comment: @JamalGadirov A $\text{deg} \;m$ polynomial has $m+1$ coefficients, so you need $m+1$ conditions.

Comment: Ok. Let say $p(x)=a_0+a_1*x+...+a_m *x^m$. Let write couples $(x_0,p(x_0)),(x_1,p(x_1)),...,(x_m,p(x_m))$ by hypothesis all components in couples are real. By Lagrange  interpolation formula if we say $p_j=p(x_j)[(x-x_0)...(x-x_m)/(x_j-x_k)]$ second product is taken over j is different from k. Then $p(x)=sum_(j=0)\(m)p_j(x)$. So  can we conclude the result

Comment: ohh  yes u r absolutely right @dxiv